# Storing drones during the winter

Tags: hardware, winter, storage

Up here in Canada, it can get kinda cold during the winter. And just because of where I tend to use my drone, it can be easier for me to store it in an outdoor (dry, but unheated) shelter than to haul it back to the house all the time.

Is it okay for drones (Eachine E520S) to stay outside at like -30°C, or should I continually bring it inside?  My guess is that it's the batteries that will suffer the most, so should I just bring them in? (lithium-ion batteries)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I can't speak for your specific drone, but I have experience with electronics and cold weather.

I would definitely store the batteries in the warm, and check the manufacturer's guidelines for the correct storage voltage (for a LiPo I think this is about 30% to 40% charge, *or 3.85 volts per cell*) It also doesn't hurt to store them in a fireproof container for extra safety.

The main hazard I've found when storing and operating electronics in freezing conditions is the risk of freeze-thaw cycles when the temperature is hovering around 0°C. Once it is cold, it's generally OK.

Additionally, if you do decide to use the aircraft during the winter take care when moving it from a cold, dry environment into a warm one - condensation will form and can cause damage or corrosion. Let it warm up thoroughly before use - if possible, seal it into a watertight bag or box before bringing it in to preserve the dry air around the drone, and wait for it to warm up before opening to minimise condensation.

Answer (score 3):

Storing drones during the winter Should be of little trouble for you. I would recommend that whether you store them say in a garage of in your home, the place of storage be dry and not humid and somewhat warmer than freezing.

Batteries should be stored in a somewhat warm environment which again should not be humid, in order to avoid any thaw/freeze cycles and avoiding any possible damage that may come about.

To be more on the safer side in order to avoid any possible misfortune or damage, I would recommend your drone be completely winterized so to speak. For myself (I am from BC), I would drain all the fuel from the drone as well if you have no intention of flying over the winter months.

In the end, I would recommend that it be brought indoors.

Answer (score 1):

The electronics will be fine if they are dry, and liPos should be able to be stored below freezing. It is, however, important to let them warm up before charging or using them to get the full performance.